# dynamically switch themes in Orchard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I had made two themes for my site.One is for front end and second is back end. The front end totally different from back-end. My senerio is that when normal user is view my site then front theme is rendered and when Administrator is logged in then back end theme is rendered. I have tested my themes that both works fine.But I don't know how to dynamically switch themes on current user status ?

Comment: Do you mean you have an admin theme and a front end theme?

Comment: my mean to say that I made two different themes which both has different styles.one theme which I will use for front site and second theme that I will use for admin panel.these both are custom themes which I did make

Comment: If by admin panel you mean Orchards admin section then you can just overwrite the default admin theme. It is discussed here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/258854

Comment: Suddenly I found an article after bit of googling that give me solution of my problem.Thankx Hazaa also for reply here is solution          http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/12/14/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms.aspx